# adding links in javascript based table field

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

The only thing I could find on the net how to do this is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27819208/adding-a-link-in-bootstrap-table) and I am still stumped, cant figure it out.

I basically have a javascript based table and I want some fields to contain a link with either an image or a simple glyphicon.

For instance fields `sheet1`,`sheet2`,`sheet3`I want to contain an image or glyph of a PDF icon since they are PDF's and so on which will link to the actual file.

Most of the articles I find on how to do this are with static tables, since mine is dynamic I am having a hard time finding info on this.

I just cant figure out where to even start with this, any ideas that can point me in the right direction would be awesome.

**jquery/bootstrap**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();

    $('#table-javascript').bootstrapTable({
        method: 'get',
        url: 'bootstrap_database.php',
        height: 600,
        cache: false,
        striped: true,
        pagination: true,
        search: true,
        pageSize: 20,
        pageList: [20, 40, 60, 100, 200],
        minimumCountColumns: 2,
        clickToSelect: true,
        columns: [{
            field: 'title',
            title: 'Title',
            align: 'center',
            sortable: true
        },{
            field: 'audio',
            title: 'Audio',
            align: 'center',
            sortable: true
        },{
            field: 'sheet1',
            title: 'Sheet 1',
            align: 'center',
            sortable: true
        },{
            field: 'sheet2',
            title: 'Sheet 2',
            align: 'center',
            sortable: true
        },{
            field: 'sheet3',
            title: 'Sheet 3',
            align: 'center',
            sortable: true
        },{
            field: 'lyrics',
            title: 'Lyrics',
            align: 'center',
            sortable: true
        },{
            field: 'sheet1notes',
            title: 'Notes 1',
            align: 'center',
            sortable: true
        },{
            field: 'sheet2notes',
            title: 'Notes 2',
            align: 'center',
            sortable: true
        },{
            field: 'sheet3notes',
            title: 'Notes 3',
            align: 'center',
            sortable: true
        }]
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <section>
        <div class="row">
            <h1>Music</h1>
            <table id="table-javascript" class="table"></table>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example: http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/,
to use formatter column option: https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table-examples/blob/master/welcome.html#L98